# Can Quantum Entanglement Be Achieved Between a Particle and Existing Particles That Are Quantum Entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-entanglement

As the above title mentions, is it theoretically possible for a particle to achieve quantum entanglement with an existing set of particles that are already entangled? I did try searching for a possible answer to this online already, but did not find any articles that go over this specific scenario so I'd like to know what is currently theorized.

Comment: Read [about 3 particle entanglement here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/292448/264772). Your question is meangingless. But I think what you wanted to ask is this only.

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy I had asked a question years ago that seems to contradict what your take on this is. Can you review this link here regarding [what is the theoretical limit of entanglement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371219/what-is-the-theoretical-limit-of-entanglement) so that you can further clarify the answer to the question I am asking here? I'd like to ensure I am not misunderstanding this and a further explanation would greatly help.

Comment: This may help - [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://www.facebook.com/veritasium/videos/parallel-worlds-probably-exist-heres-why/339179977597625/)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a particle is decayed into 2 particles (let's say A and B). Then these 2 are entangled with each other. So, if you measure one particle's momentum you can tell the momentum of the other as well.

Now imagine C comes and collides with B. If you now measure the momentum of A you cannot tell about B's current momentum because of the collision. But you can still find the combined B and C momentum. So C is not just entangled with B, but also A. That is, C came and entangled with the A and B entangled system.

Comment: Well, in the case where C comes and collides with B, you can't tell anything about the combined momentum of B and C because C could've come in with any momentum whatsoever. Your point still stands tho if you consider that B further decays into B and C (e.g., an electron emitting a photon).

Comment: @DvijD.C. free electron can't emit a photon because of energy conservation in CoM. In the nucleus, it can occur but I didn't want to write about all that so took a simple example. But in my example, we can think that C is a momentum eigen state (so it can be anywhere).

Comment: Ah, yes, bad example. In any case, replace the electron with a particle that has an internal structure, for example. My point is that if C brings in some momentum then you also need to know what that momentum is in order to conclude anything about the total momentum of B and C. You can't infer it purely from the measurement of A. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It is good to go to the basics of the definition of entanglement, which is the mathematics of quantum mechanics. If one has a complete quantum mechanical solution ( hard for many particles) for a system of particles, than these particles are entangled, because the solution is known and the spin orientations ( for the use of entanglement in the computing form)are known and depend on each other.

The answer to

> is it theoretically possible for a particle to achieve quantum entanglement with an existing set of particles that are already entangled

depends on the word  "achieve". If you mean that if you add a particle to the problem can the particles be entangled with the new particle, the answer is yes, because a new quantum mechanical wave function will describe the addition and there will be spin orientations. If you mean will the particles have the same spin orientation they had before the intrusion the answer is "probably not" as the momenta and energies introduced by the new particle may change the orientation of the spins to each  other particle, depending on the values of the input energy. Quantum  mechanics is a probabilistic theory.